# Handling exception while using shutil.copytree to copy a file where permission is denied

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following directory tree

```
Work--->subdir1--->File1
    |         |
    |         ---->File2
    |
    -->subdir2--->File3
```

There exists another similar directory tree

```
Gold--->subdir1--->File1
    |         |
    |         ---->File2
    |
    -->subdir2--->File3
```

I have to write a script to copy the `Work` directory to another location. I have been using `shutil.copytree` for the same.

The problem is, at times (but not always) I may not have permission to access some files, say, `File2` in the `Work` directory, and will get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Script.py", line 81, in <module>
shutil.copytree(source_loc,dest_loc)
File "C:\Python32\lib\shutil.py", line 239, in copytree
   raise Error(errors)
   shutil.Error: [('C:\\Work\\subdir1\\File2', 
   'C:\\Dest\\subdir1\\File2', 
"[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Work\\subdir1\\File2'")]
```

In such situations, I will have to copy those corresponding files from the `Gold` directory.
Is there a way in which I can automate the copying of the corresponding files from `Gold` directory through an exception? Say something like:

```
try:
   shutil.copytree(r'C:\Work',r'C:\Dest')
except:
   << Copy Inaccessible Files from Gold >>
```

I was initially thinking about using `os.walk`, to copy files individually. This way whenever I encounter an exception for a particular file, I will be able to copy that corresponding file from Gold. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the list of files that failed to copy from shutil.Error. From reading the source, shutil.Error contains  (src, dst, why) triplets. You can do something like:

```
try:
    shutil.copytree(srcdir, dstdir)
except shutil.Error, exc:
    errors = exc.args[0]
    for error in errors:
        src, dst, msg = error
        # Get the path to the file in Gold dir here from src
        shutil.copy2(goldsrc, dst)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I wanted to know how to get that list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `os.walk` would be the correct way to go.

`copytree` is limited. It's not designed as a sophisticated copy tool, and it also says so in its docstring:

```
XXX Consider this example code rather than the ultimate tool.
```

(This note was removed in Python 3)

Comment: Actually I don't think that the copytree actually "stops" when it encounters a file that it inaccessible. In the current situation Work folder actually contains around 70 files and the file with the said issue is somewhere in the middle (25th file to be exact)I see that the rest 69 are being copied properly.

Comment: no, you're right, i had already corrected this. it raises an error with a list of reasons, so maybe you can use that to recover.

Comment: Yes. I am new to python and I was wondering whether there is any way by which I can get that list of files which failed to copy?

Comment: @Pulimon, you can get it from shutil.Error. See my answer below